# export 'AuthServiceConfig' was not found in 'angularx-social-login' in Angular 9 app

Tags: angular, typescript, facebook-javascript-sdk

I tried to do this documentation: https://levelup.gitconnected.com/sign-in-with-facebook-oauth-in-angular-8-3a1625eceab2

this is my **app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { MaterialModule } from './material-module';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './components/login/login.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { FlexLayoutModule } from '@angular/flex-layout';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { SignUpComponent } from './components/sign-up/sign-up.component';
import { HttpClientModule, HttpClientJsonpModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { PopUpComponent } from './components/pop-up/pop-up.component';
import { SocialLoginModule, AuthServiceConfig, FacebookLoginProvider } from 'angularx-social-login';

const config = new AuthServiceConfig ([
  {
    id: FacebookLoginProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
    provider: new FacebookLoginProvider('646908969284899')
  }
]);
export function provideConfig() {
  return config;
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    SignUpComponent,
    PopUpComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MaterialModule,
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    FlexLayoutModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    HttpClientJsonpModule,
    SocialLoginModule
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: AuthServiceConfig,
      useFactory: provideConfig
    }
   ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I ran this command: `npm install --save angularx-social-login`
I get this error:

> Module
> '"../../node_modules/angularx-social-login/angularx-social-login"' has
> no exported member 'AuthServiceConfig'.ts(2305)

Anyone know what the solution is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What are your angular and angularx-social-login versions?

I think it's a guide for an old version.
You can follow this: [Angular 9 / 10 Social Login](https://github.com/abacritt/angularx-social-login)

Comment: Thanks for your response,  
My angular version is 10.0
My angularx-social-login version is 3.2.0
I will tried the new guide

Comment: You are welcome @DvirShahala! Ok, you have to follow the new guide. AuthServiceConfig now is SocialAuthServiceConfig

Comment: I follow the tutorial but i got a weird error: `core.js:4073 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'initialize' of undefined`
Did you know this issue?

Comment: @DvirShahala I've you're same versions but i hadn't this error :(

Comment: Hi I had this code. let config = new SocialAuthServiceConfig([
  {
    id: FacebookLoginProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
    provider: new FacebookLoginProvider("Facebook-App-Id", fbLoginOptions)
  }
]); but I had this error 'SocialAuthServiceConfig' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.

Comment: @Ale_Bianco Hi I had this code. const config =new SocialAuthServiceConfig([
  {
    id: GoogleLoginProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
    provider: new GoogleLoginProvider(
      environment.googleClientId
    )
  }
]); but I had this error 'SocialAuthServiceConfig' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here. can you please suggest what we can do to fix this?

Comment: @Salman4code i think you have to insert it into module providers: 
providers: [
    {
      provide: 'SocialAuthServiceConfig',
      useValue: {
        autoLogin: false,
        providers: [
          {
            id: GoogleLoginProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
            provider: new GoogleLoginProvider(
              'clientId'
            )
          },
          {
            id: FacebookLoginProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
            provider: new FacebookLoginProvider('clientId')
          }
        ]
      } as SocialAuthServiceConfig,
    }

Answer (score 3):

It has been renamed to `SocialAuthServiceConfig` in the newer versions.